# EJB @Schedule timing out method call

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.1

I am using an EJB @Schedule

```
@Schedule(hour:"18")
someProcess(){

//this code takes 10 minutes
}
```

This is failing because my cod takes > 3 minutes which is the default time in my Jboss. Is there anyway I can handle this programmatically ? I do not want to change the standalone.xml becuase that will have a bigger impact. Is there anyway I can tell JBOSS/JVM to run this as long as it takes and not time out.

Comment: Try adding `@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)`

Comment: Thanks  @Steve C, this is working for me! Can you please Answer this question? I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Schedule(hour:"18")
void someProcess(){

      //this code takes 10 minutes

}
```

in order to prevent transaction timeout from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Try `TransactionTimeout` annotation from `org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout` package if you need transactional job.

```
@TransactionTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 10)
@Schedule(year = "*", minute = "0", hour = "18", dayOfMonth = "*")
public void performHeavyJob(){
    // hmmm...Heavy Code.
}
```

Otherwise you can opt `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`